# Is it possible to regain ownership of a post I edited more than 10 times?

Tags: support, editing, community-wiki

I was wondering if I could regain ownership of the following post from last week.

[Evaluating the log gamma integral $\int_{0}^{z} \log \Gamma (x) \, \mathrm dx$ in terms of the Hurwitz zeta function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529205/the-log-gamma-integral-int-0z-log-gamma-x-mathrm-dx)

Comment: As in not have it be community wiki anymore?

Comment: Yes.  That's what I meant.

Comment: This should really have been a flag on the question rather than a question on meta.

Comment: Some answers addressing this have been posted at meta.MSE [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/1798/) and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/1797/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a post from Meta Stack Overflow that addresses it: [Is there a way to remove community wiki status?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2974/is-there-a-way-to-remove-community-wiki-status)

Here's the relevant snippet from the answer to that question (by Jeff Atwood)

> Yes—community moderators, at their discretion, can now remove
>   community wiki status from particular posts.
>
> (blurb explaining when posts are automatically made community wiki)
>
> However, if you feel your post has been unfairly converted to
>   community wiki and deserves special treatment, you can flag it for
>   moderator attention and plead your case to a community moderator.

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't even know about flaging.

Comment: This is indeed the best course of action. Remember to flag the post as "other" and explain why you think it should be un-CW-ed.